# append! fails with "no method matching length" when custom type in mix

Tags: julia

I've just finished minimal basics for Julia and for better understanding of constructs was trying solving some simple problems.

In a case where I've a custom struct say `HttpRequest`, then create an Array of `HttpRequest Arrays` say `sampleArr`.

My requirement is to dynamically update `HttpRequest Array` in `sampleArr[index]`.

While trying `append!` I get following error

`ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching length(::HttpRequest)`

Following code can be used as sample for what I'm trying to do

```
#!/usr/bin/env julia

struct HttpRequest
  httpMethod
  httpHost
  httpBlah
end

reqA = HttpRequest("GET", "1.1.1.1", "yada")
reqB = HttpRequest("PUT", "1.1.1.1", "blah")
reqC = HttpRequest("GET", "2.3.2.3", "boka")
reqD = HttpRequest("POST", "8.1.8.1", "juka")
reqE = HttpRequest("PUT", "4.4.4.4", "kula")

sampleArrLen = 10
sampleArr = Array{Array, 1}(undef,sampleArrLen)

sampleArr[5] = [reqA]
append!(sampleArr[5], reqB)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `push!` instead of `append!`, like this:

```
julia> push!(sampleArr[5], reqB)
2-element Array{HttpRequest,1}:
 HttpRequest("GET", "1.1.1.1", "yada")
 HttpRequest("PUT", "1.1.1.1", "blah")

julia> sampleArr
10-element Array{Array,1}:
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
    HttpRequest[HttpRequest("GET", "1.1.1.1", "yada"), HttpRequest("PUT", "1.1.1.1", "blah")]
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
```

The difference between `push!` and `append!` is that `push!` pushes a single element to a collection and `append!` appends all elements of some other collection to an end of a collection. Therefore the following would work `append!(sampleArr[5], [reqB])` and give the same result as `push!(sampleArr[5], reqB)`. The difference here is that you wrap `reqB` in an array, so now you are appending a single element collection to `sampleArr`.